# Clear grid view and regenerate it in android

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview

I had a grid view on page load it populated.I have a sync button when I am clicking this it should regenerate the grid view.How to do that.

I am using

`ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this);
                gridview.setAdapter(adapter);`

**Code in detail**

```
try {
            if(stringArrayPdfUrlForLocalDB.length>0)
            {
                for(int i=0 ; i < stringArrayPdfUrlForLocalDB.length ; i++)
                {
                    String fileName = getOnlyFileName(stringArrayPdfUrlForLocalDB[i]);
                    String imageName = getImageName(stringArrayPdfUrlForLocalDB[i]);
                    String BookId   = stringArrayBookId[i];

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File Name: "+fileName+"\nBookId: "+BookId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    db.open();        
                    long id = db.insertRecord(BookId, fileName + ".pdf", imageName);        
                    db.close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not getting any book form server.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            //populate grid view

            ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this);
            gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Comment: call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter.

Comment: How to add that in my code example

Comment: add notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter when you click sync button

Answer (score 1):

after click button:

load your data first

after that just do.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

---

**Edited:**

```
ImageAdapter adapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this);
```

create this adapter to Global Variable after doing that code is:

```
adapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this);
gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

change this code in your code:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseBody,
            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (responseBody != null) {
                processResponce(responseBody);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty Responce.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
```

Comment: My code zip file http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=ge8378d0b7e7716f29992620196dc3f91ebb1b025e

Comment: i gor access denide in your web services but i have just change your code check my edited ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15879814/1168654

Comment: I have used adapter = new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this);
gridview.setAdapter(adapter);